# Location of on my iPad in root perspective

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, jailbreak, root

What is the location of On My iPad in the Files app in root perspective?

I have iPadOS 13.3.1 which is jailbroken

Comment: Create a file in "On My iPad", then run `find / -name "name-of-file"`?

Comment: Try `/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/group.com.apple.localstorage`